# How Don Tommasino and Don Corleone know each other?

Tags: character, the-godfather

In *The Godfather*, Tommasino is shown to be a close and loyal friend of Vito.

- He helps Vito achieving his vendetta against Don Ciccio, and literally takes a bullet for him.
- He hides Michael in Sicily after Sollozo and McCluskey hit.

However, as he left Sicily as a young child and returns there for the first time as an adult to perform his vendetta, I wonder how did he built a strong and loyal relationship with Tommasino?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not stated explicitly in the movie and the novel merely refers to Vito performing a great service for Don Tommasino

> Michael had been transported from the ship docked at Palermo to the interior of the Sicilian island, to the very heart of a province controlled by the Mafia, where the **local capo-mafioso was greatly indebted to his father for some past service**.
>
> ...
>
> The capo-mafioso was a man in his late fifties named Don Tommasino
>
> <sup>*The Godfather* - Mario Puzo</sup>